# How to observe the class change and do something in Jquery for shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, r, shiny

I added a shiny header dropdown menu button. It will open contents when its button clicked, and close contents if click the button again or click outside of contents. Here is what I would like to achieve:

- When click the dropdown menu button, show the contents and also increase the main page's padding-top to 40px.
- When I click the dropdown menu button again or click anywhere outside of contents, the main page's padding-top is going back to 20px.

This can achieve mostly, but there is one thing still needed to be fixed:

- when we click outside of contents, it will not go to the if else loop. So it will not change paddings. In other words, if we close the content by clicking outside the contents, the paddings will not change until we click the dropdown button again.

How to improve this, or is there a better way? Alternatively, we can avoid closing contents by clicking anywhere outside.

I apologize I am not able to make a reproducible example.  Please help at you convenience. Thank you in advance!

Comment: add your html and css code too

Comment: I made the app from shiny codes and I extract the html related to the dropdown button.
`<li class="dropdown" id="dropdown111" style="">`
 `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js

```
const header = $('.header');
const button = $('#dropdown111');

const closeMenu = function({ target }) {
  console.log('doc click triggered')
  if (!target.classList.contains('header') && target.id !== 'dropdown111') {
    header.removeClass('open');
  }
  if (!header.hasClass('open')) {
    $(document).off('click', closeMenu);
  }
}

button.on('click', function () {
  header.toggleClass('open');
  if (header.hasClass('open')) {
    $(document).click(closeMenu);
  }
})
```

css

```
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #fff;
}

.header.open {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

html

```
<header class="header">
  This is your header
</header>
<button id="dropdown111">This is your button</button>
```

example
https://codepen.io/michaelmano/pen/BaWjqxY?editors=1111